# How should I Merge mounted drive(Volume) with root drive in AWS EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, mount, amazon-ami, diskspace

I have mounted 600 GB of extra space in my AWS EC2 at `/data`. But as I started using Jenkins i realized that My Jenkins is not using any of that extra space and now I am left with only 1.5 GB of storage.

Is there any way to merge the extra storage with root storage?

Result of `df -h` command

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.9G   68K  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  6.3G  1.5G  82% /
/dev/xvdf       600G  1.8G  598G   1% /data
```

I want to merge `/dev/xvda1` and `/dev/xvdf`.

Is it even possible?

Edit: Someone suggested to move my jenkins to new drive. If it will not not hamper my current work then i think it will be a good solution. Any opinions on this?

Comment: Woudn't it be better to [change](https://dzone.com/articles/jenkins-02-changing-home-directory) jenkins folder to use the new drive?

Comment: Will it hamper my active pipelines in any way? I was thinking of this but was not sure weather anything will brake in my jenkinsand it will take much more time.

Comment: What about [resizing the root ebs volume](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/) and deleting the unused one?

Comment: I hope https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/ this can help

Answer (score 0):

Quick way:

you can stop your jenkins instance and create AMI image on it.

Then create base on this image as a new EC2 instance with large storage directly.

Comment: To be honest, in my organisation this will take much more time, getting approval and all.